# Area of a part of a paraboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area, surfaces

I have to evaluate the are of the paraboloid
$$z=7.2^2-x^2-y^2$$
which is above the plane $z=2.17^2$.

Since the area is
$$S=\iint\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}\;dA$$
then
$$S=\iint\sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2}\;dA=\iint\sqrt{1+4(x^2+y^2)}\;dA$$

If $z=2.17^2$, I get the circumference
$$x^2+y^2=7.2^2-2.17^2$$
Therefore, in polar coordinates, the area of the surface will be
$$S=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{7.2^2-2.17^2}}\sqrt{1+4r^2}\cdot r dr d\theta$$
Is it correct?

Comment: Looks OK to me.